# Is there a tool to visualize our system that comprises several distinct processes?

Tags: software-development

We have several programs that run, some on a timer, some on an event.  They all take data from one place, and put it another place.  We are getting lost in who depends on who.  When some data item is not delivered, it is hard to determine which piece didn't do its job.  Initially, all we know is that it didn't arrive at the end.

Is there some tool that already exists that I could customize or configure?  Ideally, a graph that shows communication as connecting lines.  When information doesn't arrive in a reasonable amount of time, the connecting line goes red.

It sounds like something someone would have already done, but I can't think of it.

Comment: It sounds like you need a redesign and documentation , not debugging